# Jenkins foreground task

Tags: jenkins, cocos2d-x

I have two Jenkins machines.
Both run windows batch commands

When I start programs on one, they start in the background (Staging box).
When I start programs on the other, they start in the foreground, and you can see the window and watch the program as it's running (Production box).

I'm trying to test a program which only works in the foreground (it's a Cocos game executable and probably needs to be in the foreground to run properly).

I need to know what Jenkins-settings to change so that my staging-Jenkins box behaves the same as my Production-Jenkins box.

I have already tried:
The jenkins windows service is running as the currently logged in user.

Most other questions talk about forcing it to the background, which is the opposite of my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

If you are running Jenkins as a Windows service, then the service is running in the background, and thus the programs started by Jenkins will also be run in the background.

If you run Jenkins in the foreground (Ie, typing "java -jar jenkins.war" in a console window), then programs started by Jenkins will also be in the foreground (since the foreground console window is the Jenkins process).

Jenkins-Slaves run as a service, but they run with a foreground window, so they show up in the foreground of the slave machine.

Comment: For last 4 days, I'm struggling to get a bat -> vbs -> excel vba to work properly. Thanks a ton the cool idea. I wish I searched for this requirement on day 1.

Answer (score 0):

No need to run jenkins as jar. Rather one can configure the same system(master/ or some other system) as slave in Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes. Then connect the slave system with master.

In the jenkins job configuration, select node name in the job general configuration section mentioning the slave system where job will be running. 
Then build the job. It worked for me.

Comment: I ultimately got everything working, but it's still not quite ideal.  There's no way to get a Jenkins that is running as a service to pop a foreground window.  Cocos works in the background if you get the options right, but a browser window will not (We test on multiple environments/languages).